PySpark: Element-wise sum ALL DenseVectors in each cell of a dataframe
I need to element-wise sum ALL DenseVectors for each sentence. There can be multiple DenseVectors (per sentence) in each row's cell, i.e. embeddings.
I'll explain with the help of multiple lists in a cell. Take the following example:
+----------------------------------+
|abc                               |
+----------------------------------+
|[[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [1.2, 2.2, 3.2]]|
|[[2.0, 3.0, 4.0], [3.1, 4.1, 5.1]]|
|[[3.0, 4.0, 5.0], [4.3, 5.3, 6.3]]|
|[[4.0, 5.0, 6.0], [5.2, 4.2, 7.2]]|
+----------------------------------+

The output required is:
+-----------------+
|abc              |
+-----------------+
|[2.2, 4.2,  6.2]|
|[5.1, 7.1,  9.1]|
|[7.3, 9.3, 11.3]|
|[9.2, 9.2, 13.2]|
+-----------------+

I've tried a few ways on the following lines but nothing seems to work.
schema = StructType([
  StructField("abc", ArrayType(ArrayType(FloatType())), True)
])

test_data = [
    Row([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [1.2, 2.2, 3.2]]),
    Row([[2.0, 3.0, 4.0], [3.1, 4.1, 5.1]]),
    Row([[3.0, 4.0, 5.0], [4.3, 5.3, 6.3]]),
    Row([[4.0, 5.0, 6.0], [5.2, 4.2, 7.2]])
    ]

test_df = spark.createDataFrame(data=test_data, schema=schema)

test_df.groupBy("abc").agg(array([sum(col("abc")[i].getItem(j)) for j in range(3) for i in range(len(test_df.select('abc').first()[0]))]).alias("sum")).show(truncate=False)

test_df.groupBy("abc").agg(array(*[array(*[sum(col("abc")[i].getItem(j)) for j in range(3) for i in range(len(test_df.select('abc').first()[0]))])]).alias("sum")).show(truncate=False)

test_df.groupBy("abc").agg(array(*[array(*[sum(col("abc")[i].getItem(j)) for i in range(len(test_df.select('abc').first()[0]))]) for j in range(3) ]).alias("sum")).show(truncate=False)


You can use zip_with to do the element wise addition. Then, reduce to aggregate into 1 final array.
df = (df.withColumn('abc', F.reduce(
         'abc', 
         F.array([F.lit(0.0), F.lit(0.0), F.lit(0.0)]), 
         lambda acc, x: F.zip_with(acc, x, lambda iacc, ix: iacc + ix))))

============================================
UPDATE
If your array size is fixed, you can change F.array part to create the fixed size array as
F.array([F.lit(0.0) for x in range(1064)])

and to your second question, if you are using Pyspark 3.1-<3.5, you can use aggregate. Function interface is same, so just change reduce to aggregate.
If your array size is dynamic, you can try this to return the initial array within the aggregation function.
df = (df.withColumn('abc',  F.aggregate(
         'abc', 
         F.array().cast('array<double>'), 
         lambda acc, x: (F.when(F.size(acc) < 1, x)
                         .otherwise(F.zip_with(acc, x, lambda iacc, ix: iacc + ix))))))


Thank you so much for your response. A follow-up question here: Since this is going to be used in dense embeddings of size 768, 1064 or so, how would you modify the F.array() part?

Also, I'm using pyspark 3.3.1 and it seems pyspark.sql.functions.reduce was introduced in pyspark 3.5.0

@Shruti I updated my answer. Please check and let me know if you have questions.

Thank you so much! This solved my problem.
